# How to get the hidden element value in Protractor.NET?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, protractor-net

I have an input type hidden which stores a primary key id. How can I get the hidden type value? Is that possible to get the value using Protractor.NET?

Below is my code to get the Id value but in vain

```
 NgWebDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("editor.myModel.id"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Evaluate()`](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/blob/79f40bd7bfee5251b13ae520026cf151f2a3d2de/src/Protractor/NgWebElement.cs#L240) to evaluate the value of the model in the context of the element:

```
element.Evaluate("editor.myModel.id")
```

Comment: Thanks, Alecxe. I had used the evaluate method to get the hidden value. Below is the solution

var id = NgWebDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("editor.myModel.id"))
                .Evaluate("editor.myModel.id");